# REquest weblink to download/install Perl Expect module

Tags: perl

Iam looking for a weblink, where I can download perl packages/modules like expect.pm, Stty.pm for HP itanium machine as well as for AIX flavor unix machine.
I tried to google alot, but in vain.
Can somebody help me, pointing to the locations, so that i can download/install the same.

Thanks in advance,
Roopesh Kumar M.

Comment: Added bounty to find out where AIX packages are available that were made with the native compiler.

Answer (score 4):

http://search.cpan.org/

Modules are distributed as platform non-specific source code.

Given a properly set up Perl environment, you should be able to type

```
cpan Module::Name
```

from the shell to install a given module (and its dependencies). Note that module names are case sensitive.

Comment: Will CPAN modules work across platforms ? iam looking one for HP Itanium. Just wanted to confirm.

Comment: I refer you back to line 2 of my answer.

Comment: Is you're HP Itanium equipped with gcc, g++, make ?

Comment: @hlynur, yes.. i have make in my hp itanium machine. But no gcc or g++ is present.

Answer (score 0):

From [#p5p](https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/index.cgi?p5p):

```
[17:47] <daxim> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414210   HP and AIX modules? Tux?
[17:52] <Tux> daxim: short answer
[17:52] <purl> short answer is "not very"
[17:53] <Tux> for HP-UX there is no provider that has `loose' modules available to add, like the most linux vendors do
[17:53] <daxim> so unless they install gcc, they're screwed wrt non-pure perl modules, right?
[17:53] <Tux> for AIX I know of about no other perl providers than IBM itself
[17:53] <Tux> and they ship archaic versions
[17:53] <Tux> daxim, correct
[17:54] <Tux> or, for HP-UX, install the most recent version of my or AS' perl and ask me or AS very friendly to make it avail;able
[17:54] <Tux> I'm not jumping with joy to do so BTW
```

Tux is http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand, AS is http://activestate.com/activeperl.

Answer (score 0):

I found one link regarding **[AIX Open Source Packages](http://www.perzl.org/aix)** but i dont know how reliable it is.

As i am reading, i found Important Notes like:

- **These web pages are a private initiative of mine (Michael Perzl) and are in no way endorsed nor supported by IBM!**
- **While the web pages are hosted here
  at perzl.org the actual downloads
  (binary and source RPMs) will take
  place from my other web site
  oss4aix.org due to space constraints
  of the web server.**

I think the one who are working on **AIX flavor** can confirm it by using this link that whether it is reliable or not.

Regarding Active State(AS): **AIX modules available Only in ActivePerl Business, Enterprise, and OEM Editions.**